# PHPickerViewControllerDelegate — special handling for limited case? Why is didFinishPicking not working seamlessly?

Tags: ios, swift, photokit, phpickerviewcontroller

I am using the new PHPickerViewController & Delegate on iOS15+.

I want my code to get get a callback from the picker (regardless of full photo access or limited) that the user has selected photo x, y, and z to attach to this chat. I'd like this callback regardless of the level of access given to my app to the photo library.

Here is how I show the photo picker:

```swift
            var configuration = PHPickerConfiguration(photoLibrary: .shared())
            // Set the filter type to images only for now
            configuration.filter = PHPickerFilter.any(of: [.images])
            // Set the mode to avoid transcoding, if possible, if your app supports arbitrary image/video encodings.
            configuration.preferredAssetRepresentationMode = .compatible
            // Set the selection behavior to respect the user’s selection order.
            configuration.selection = .ordered
            // Set the selection limit to enable multiselection.
            configuration.selectionLimit = 8
            // Set the preselected asset identifiers with the identifiers that the app tracks.
            configuration.preselectedAssetIdentifiers = self.selectedAssetIdentifiers
            // Show it
            let picker = PHPickerViewController(configuration: configuration)
            picker.delegate = self
            (UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate)?.window?.rootViewController?.present(picker, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

And here is my delegate:

```swift
func picker(_ picker: PHPickerViewController, didFinishPicking results: [PHPickerResult]) {
        dismiss(animated: true)
        let existingSelection = self.selection
        var newSelection = [String: PHPickerResult]()
        for result in results {
            let identifier = result.assetIdentifier!
            newSelection[identifier] = existingSelection[identifier] ?? result
        }
        
        // Track the selection in case the user deselects it later.
        _selection = newSelection
        selectedAssetIdentifiers = results.map(\.assetIdentifier!)
        selectedAssetIdentifierIterator = selectedAssetIdentifiers.makeIterator()
        
        // Convert and load into the attachment manager
        let fetchResult = PHAsset.fetchAssets(withLocalIdentifiers: results.compactMap(\.assetIdentifier), options: nil)
        // Loop through the objects in the fetch result using enumerateObjects
        fetchResult.enumerateObjects { (asset, index, stop) in
            // Do something with 'asset' and 'index'\
            let options = PHImageRequestOptions()
            options.deliveryMode = .highQualityFormat
            options.resizeMode = .fast
            options.isNetworkAccessAllowed = true
            // Ideally we handle this better in the UI without freezing.
            options.isSynchronous = true
            
            let image = asset.image(targetSize: PHImageManagerMaximumSize, contentMode: PHImageContentMode.default, options: options)
            let handled = self.attachmentManager.handleInput(of: image)
            if !handled {
                // throw error
            }
        }
    }
```

In the limited photo mode, it seems like my didFinishPicking delegate method is never called—or at least never called in situations where the user has selected a photo from their library that they did not give me permission with the first time round.

Are there other methods I need to implement to support this privacy focused mode?

---

Here is the user flow generally, use case is a chat app where users can pick photos to attach to a message. The user selects 'use only selected photos', which then opens the picker to select which photos to give the app access to

[image: privacy mode]
[image: permission picker]

After that photo picker modal, nothing happens in privacy mode. No delegate methods are called, nothing. So my app now has access to certain photos—however, I'd like/need the user to further pick which photos, of the allowed photos, to attach to this specific chat.

If the user had selected full access, they would get a similar picker, but the delegate methods would fire and tell me which photos the user picked.

This is where my confusion is. I can't find a definitive source for handling this case for what I expected to be a straight forward application of "User picks photos, I get photo in a callback so I can upload it to my backend"

Comment: Here are a few things to keep in mind when we use PHPickerViewController in constrained mode: 1. Check Permissions, 2. Handle Unavailable Photos 3. Request Permissions.

Comment: If you want i can post my delegate approach that handles unavailable photographs

Comment: I would like that thank you @arpan.r! I think I have been misled by Apple's words on this page (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/photokit/delivering_an_enhanced_privacy_experience_in_your_photos_app): "The first time your app performs an operation that requires authorization, the system automatically and asynchronously prompts the user for it.", which made me think I didn't need to handle this special case.

Comment: Can you clarify your question by better describing how you setup and make use of the photo picker in "limited photo mode"?

Comment: You also need to clarify your question. It's not entirely clear what your exact issue is or what problem you are trying to solve. Is the problem with what pictures a user can select or is it with what items are given to you in the delegate method?

Comment: Thanks for the nudge @HangarRash. I've added some user flow screenshots to the question. 

I just want my code to get get a callback from the picker (regardless of full photo access or limited) that the user has selected photo x, y, and z to attach to this chat.

Comment: And let me know if further clarifications are needed, happy to add.

Answer (score 2):

I think there is some confusion in what you are trying to do. It sounds like you have a messaging app where you want to allow the user to select some photos to attach to a message. But your question and code seem to be confusing how `PHPickerViewController` works and how photo permissions work.

If your app only uses `PHPickerViewController` to allow the user to select photos then your app will never prompt the user for any permission and the user won't be able to restrict your app to only specific photos. The mere fact that a user selects a photo from the picker means they are implicitly granting your app permission to load that image. However, you need to load the image using the `PHPickerResult` given to you in the delegate method.

If your app uses `PHPhotoLibrary` or `PHAsset` to fetch assets, then your app must obtain permission to access the library and the user may limit your app to only specific photos.

The likely solution to your code is to update your delegate code to iterate the `PHPickerResult` array and use each result's `itemProvider` property to get the `UIImage` of the selected photo.

If needed you can keep track of the `assetIdentifier` of each picker result if you want to preselect the photos in the picker.

By eliminating the use of `PHAsset` and the `fetch` calls, you don't need any permissions or any of the photo related privacy strings in your Info.plist.

For example code showing how to get the `UIImage` for each of the `PHPickerResult` in the delegate, see [iOS 14: PHPickerViewController is there any way to load all assets at the same time PHPickerResult](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68944319/ios-14-phpickerviewcontroller-is-there-any-way-to-load-all-assets-at-the-same-t)

Comment: If there's something I'm not covering in this answer, let me know so I can address it. Clarify your question as needed as well.

Comment: I think you are right, I didn't realize that the way I am fetching photos may be causing issues. Do you have a source / sample code for retrieving the UIImage from the itemProvider? I'll work on making this change today to see if I get some clarity.

Comment: @Msencenb I just added a bit to the end of my answer with a link to a question with answers that show how to get the images from the picker results.

Comment: A word of advice, fetching as UIImage will fail in various normal conditions, like fetching a large image on a less powerful iPhone. I posted a code snippet on using copying file url, which from my (painstaking) experience always works.

Comment: Agreed that I've mixed these APIs inappropriately. For the loading of these images, does the built in loadObject handle optimized storage / icloud network photos? Or is that why you load from file urls Oscar?

Comment: All the item provider api's handle those things. My comment about loadObject is regarding some providers simply refusing to load large files as UIImage's if the device is resource constrained.

Comment: Or just randomly... I've bumped into a bunch of corners in this API. Feel free to make the same mistakes tho :P I highly recommend using the fileRepresentation method.

Comment: Makes sense - I'll need to deal with it. I've also seen this more bare bones technique: https://christianselig.com/2020/09/phpickerviewcontroller-efficiently/

Comment: @OscarApeland and Msencenb - let's keep in mind that the specific details of the exact code used to obtain an image from an item provider is beyond the scope of the original question. The important part of this question is avoiding the issues of the photo permissions. If the OP wants to nail down the best way to obtain an image from an item provider, then that is best addressed in a separate question if the need arises.

Comment: Just trying to help a newcomer. This API can be confusing. Also imo the dev from that blog post makes a lot of hacky stuff, I’d rather view the referenced sources.

Comment: Thanks to both of you—I was able to submit an update today that fixed the original issue of popping the permission dialog due to me accessing the PHAsset. Sounds like there is a lot of optimizations and pitfalls for actually getting the image, but I'm happy with the progress for today.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to avoid needing to ever prompt the user for Photo Library permissions then instead of using the asset identifiers to perform a PhotoKit fetch followed by PHImageManager requests then I'd suggest just getting the image data directly off the resulting PhotosPickerItems like what's documented here: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/photokit/photospicker

and here:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/photokit/bringing_photos_picker_to_your_swiftui_app

By doing so, the user will never be shown a prompt asking to give your app access.

If your app is in Limited Access mode already then the assets it has access to via PhotoKit are not extended to include assets selected with the PhotosPicker. That is done via the two `presentLimitedLibraryPicker` apis here: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/photokit/phphotolibrary/3616113-presentlimitedlibrarypicker

Comment: PhotosPicker is a SwiftUI specific tool, which I am unfortunately not using (I should have put that in the description). 

I do expect the LimitedLibraryPicker is what I will use-I'm looking for a canonical answer for how to use that picker as none of the official Apple Example projects handle limited access mode or use that method. In particular their sample projects don't handle the typical "I am a messaging app and want to attach a photo" situation.

Comment: it would be better to provide some code snippets